# Regex "start of string" anchor not working

Tags: regex, bash

The regex I'm working with at the moment is as follows:

```
^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$
```

I'm trying to match all floating point numbers, but ONLY the number. For example, the following should match:

- 6.0
- 1.22E3
- -2
- 2.99999e-12

However, the following should NOT match:

- somestring///////6.0

I've tested the above regex on [this validation site](http://regexraptor.net/) and it works as expected. When running it in my bash script, however, nothing at all matches.

This is my bash code:

```
if [[ "$VAL" =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[0-9]+)?$ ]]
    then
        echo $VAL, "is a number"
    else
        echo $VAL, "is not a number"
fi
```

I've tried removing the anchors, and it matches any strings that contain floating points. However, strings like "//////6.00007" match. The $ anchor works as expected; however, the ^ does not.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions for troubleshooting this issue.

Thanks!

**Edit 1**

Removed bad examples

**Edit 2**

I ran the regex in its own `foo.sh` as suggested by @lurker and the code ran as expected with my test cases. So I looked at what was being compared with the regex. When I `echo`ed what was being compared, everything looked fine, so it made zero sense as to why the regex wasn't matching.

Then I began to suspect that `echo` wasn't displaying what was *actually* in `$VAL` for some reason.

So I ran this: `NEWVAL=(echo $VAL)` as a temporary workaround until I can figure out what's going on.

Comment: I tried your regex and script as-is, and they seem to work fine for me. `"//////6.00007" came out "is not a number".

Comment: Strange. What are the possibilities? Why would you running the script work and not me?

Comment: How did you run your script? Show exactly what you did. I put your code into a file `foo.sh`, then `export VAL="6"` and ran `bash foo.sh` and it said, `6, is a number`. I then did `export VAL="///////6.000007"` and ran `bash foo.sh` and it said, `///////6.000007, is not a number`. You can do `bash --version` and report what version of `bash` you are using.

Comment: Two of your examples, 1.22E3.7 and 2.99999e-0.0001, have decimal places in the exponent but your regex does not allow for that.

Comment: @lurker As you did, I put the regex in its own script and tested it with `export VAL="6"`. It worked. I tried it with several other test cases, and they worked, too. This tells me that the regex isn't the problem. So I `echo`ed what I was comparing and they looked as expected. Finally I decided that `echo` must not be showing me what's _actually_ in the variable, so I went ahead and did a `NEWVAR=$(echo VAL)` and compared `NEWVAR` with the regex. It works as expected now.

Comment: Use `declare -p varname`, not `echo "$varname"` (and *especially* not `echo $varname`) for reliable results.

Comment: `printf '%q\n' "$varname"` is also trustworthy.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Sure enough, there was a leading newline. I had no idea that `echo` strips those sorts of characters. Thank you so much!

Comment: To explain what happens -- an unquoted expansion, like the `$foo` in `echo $foo`, string-splits the contents of the variable on characters in IFS -- by default, newlines, tabs and spaces -- and then evaluates each result of that split operation as a glob to come up with the list of arguments to substitute in place. Thus, your newlines simply disappear -- they're being split on -- and non-whitespace contents are passed as separate arguments to `echo`, which then uses a simple space to separate such arguments.

Comment: ...the glob expansion also means that if `var='*'`, then `echo $var` will list filenames in your current directory, whereas `echo "$var"` will correctly emit the asterisk. There are actually a bunch of other places where `echo` has surprising or underspecified behavior -- [the POSIX spec for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) outright suggests `printf` as a replacement (see APPLICATION USAGE and RATIONALE sections).

Comment: ...one of the really important points, though, is that it's not actually `echo` itself that's stripping out the newlines -- it's the unquoted expansion behavior doing that; the newlines are already gone before `echo` is even started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the variables that I was comparing with my regex had leading newlines on them (e.g. `"\n2.3333"`) that were being stripped away with `echo`. So, when I displayed the values to the screen with `echo` I would see the stripped version of my variable, which was not what was being compared with the regex.

Lesson learned: `echo` isn't always trustworthy. Per @CharlesDuffy's comment, use one of the following to see what's *actually* in your variables: `declare -p varname` or `printf '%q\n' "$varname"` but do ***not*** use `echo $varname`.

Comment: It's much simpler to use `echo "$var"`

Answer (score 1):

Your regex does not allow decimals in the exponent. Exponents may have decimals, so your either need to change your definition of what a 'number' is or you need to change your regex.

Assuming the later, here is a correction (Bash 4.4):

```
echo "6.0
1.22E3.7
-2
2.99999e-0.0001
somestring///////6.0" >/tmp/f1.txt

while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do 
    if [[ "$line" =~ ^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+([eE][-+]?[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]+)?$ ]]
        then
            echo $line, "is a number"
        else
            echo $line, "is not a number"
    fi
done < /tmp/f1.txt
```

Prints:

```
6.0, is a number
1.22E3.7, is a number
-2, is a number
2.99999e-0.0001, is a number
somestring///////6.0, is not a number
```

**BUT** you should know, that most consider the only two legit numbers in your list to be `6.0` and `-2`. Easy way to test is with `awk`:

```
$ awk '$1+0==$1{print $0 " is a number"; next} {print $0 " not a number"}' /tmp/f1.txt
6.0 is a number
1.22E3.7 not a number
-2 is a number
2.99999e-0.0001 not a number
somestring///////6.0 not a number
```

The same C language function that `awk` uses to convert a string to a float is used by many other languages (Ruby, Perl, Python, C, C++, Swift, etc etc) so if you consider your format valid, you are probably going to be writing your own conversion routine as well.

For example, in most languages your can enter `10**1.5` as legit float literal. No language I know of accepts decimal numbers after the `e` in a string of the form `'xx.zzEyy.y'`

Comment: I apologize, those "numbers" that I had in my post were bad examples off the top of my head and were not actual values that would be compared with the regex. As it turns out, for some reason the values that were stored in `$VAL` contained something different from what was printed to the screen when I ran `echo $VAL` on them. So I did this: `NEWVAR=$(echo $VAL)` and now it works as expected. I have no idea why, but it does.

Comment: I'd expect that your `$VAL` contains leading whitespace. `echo $VAL` word-splits and glob-expands your variable's contents rather than printing those contents as-is, so it would be masking that bug.