# bash allow only positive integer or positive integer with decimal point

Tags: bash

```
price="1.11"
case $price in
            ''|*[!0-9]*) echo "It is not an integer.";
            ;;
        esac
```

`Output: It is not an integer`.

The above code is able to verify positive integer only.

How do allow positive integer with decimal point? Have been searching through the internet to no avail

Comment: The `!` actually means it is *not* an integer.

Comment: Possibly duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970586/regex-start-of-string-anchor-not-working

Comment: When you say "integer with decimal point", do you mean an integer optionally followed by a full stop, or do you actually mean "floating point number"?

Comment: I mean an integer optionally followed by a full stop. E.g. 18 or 18.12. I'm checking whether the user has enter a valid price.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this in a POSIX-compatible way is tricky; your current pattern matches *non*-integers. Two `bash` extensions make this fairly easy:

1. Use extended patterns

   ```
   shopt -s extglob
   case $price in
       # +([0-9]) - match one or more integer digits
       # ?(.+([0-9])) - match an optional dot followed by zero or more digits
       +([0-9]))?(.*([0-9]))) echo "It is an integer" ;;
       *) echo "Not an integer"
   esac
   ```
2. Use a regular expression

   ```
   if [[ $price =~ ^[0-9]+(.?[0-9]*)$ ]]; then
       echo "It is an integer"
   else
       echo "Not an integer"
   fi
   ```

(In theory, you should be able to use the POSIX command `expr` to do regular expression matching as well; I'm having trouble getting it to work, and you haven't specified POSIX compatibility as a requirement, so I'm not going to worry about it. POSIX pattern matching isn't powerful enough to match arbitrarily long strings of digits.)

---

If you only want to match a "decimalized" integer, rather than arbitrary floating point values, it is of course simpler:

1. The extended pattern `+([0-9])?(.)`
2. The regular expression `[0-9]+\.?`

Comment: You seem to be checking for optional figures after the decimal point, but of course, that makes the number not an integer.

Comment: I read too much into the question, it seems; only match, e.g., `6.` in addition to `6`?

Comment: Thanks. but adding on, how do i check if the number is in positive value? tried if [[ $price =~ [0-9]+\.? ]] && [[ $price -lt 0 ]]. But failed :(

Comment: That should work. Note that the regular expression does not allow a negative sign (at least, the corrected anchored version I added to the answer does not), so there shouldn't be a need for the comparison.

Comment: IT WORKS! Thanks so much :D

Answer (score -1):

Try this regular expression `^(0*[1-9][0-9]*(\.[0-9]+)?|0+\.[0-9]*[1-9][0-9]*)$`

Comment: Did you test this in the context of a `bash` `case` statement?

Comment: Thanks.. but It seems to have some syntax error near unexpected token `('